# Faster connection throught ssh tunnel on DataGrip

Tags: ssh, datagrip

I'm using DataGrip in a daily usage to access databases that are most of the time accessible only through SSH tunnel.

DataGrip allows to create a SSH tunnel directly in it's configuration, which is really useful but unfortunately it is also really disappointing in term of performence.

I get around 5sec of delay to get the data on screen for each request. I have good network, simple tables and good computer. The problem is from DataGrip's way to create and/or use SSH tunnel.

If I create the tunnel by hand and point it on DataGrip, then I get really fancy performence with less than half a second to get my data.
Especially if I create a no compression tunnel:
`ssh -T -o Compression=no -x -L8123:ip:8123 user@ip`

Last point, I was on Linux few month ago and I had the same problem, changing to Windows didn't change the behavior of DataGrip.

I firstly thought that the tunnel is created each time a request is performed, but I can see the tunnel using netstat:

`TCP    someip:53248      somedistantmachine:ssh        ESTABLISHED`

I wanted to know if you guys have found a way to change SSH tunnel settings on DataGrip to get better performence with the built-in solution, or if it's inherent to DataGrip and then impossible to improve ?

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr Unlikely you can improve performance on your own.

Hi! I’m responsible for the SSH subsystem in IntelliJ-based IDEs. The reason why you haven’t got any change after switching from Linux to Windows is because our SSH client uses [SSHJ](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/) library which is written in Java. Frankly, I had been told about slow data transfer over SSH channels only once before this post, so I haven’t paid much attention to the problem.

Nevertheless, I’ve measured our tunnels' performance and have found out that our SSH tunnels can be really slow, up to 12 times depending on the setup. So I’ve created an issue in our tracker: [IDEA-256821](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256821). I’d appreciate it if you could describe your set up in the issue: ping round-trip time, if you use any VPN or something like that, how much data your database sends to DataGrip, etc.

Comment: Thanks for considering my problem ! I will complete this ticket ;)